# LCD Display not working, always white and random bars

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro 13-inch, late 2011 which some time ago started suffering this [1] issue and I was wondering if do someone know how to ensure if the fault comes from the LCD cable or the LCD display?

I've tried disassembling the MacBook to check for cable connections, I even tried removing the LCD display and attaching an external one via thunderbolt to HDMI connector and it worked fine on the external display. In fact attaching an external display i'ts the way I've worked around the problem.

Also I've tried resetting SMC, NRAM and PRAM without  luck.

In case i would need to replace the LCD display, I also would like to know which ones would fit better on the MacBook. I mean, over the years Apple improved LCD display by providing better image resolution and lowering power consumption so i would like to know which technical data should i look for in order to know if the new LCD Display would work on my MacBook while checking for those improvements

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOgS0RNFk30

**Edit 2018.04.28**

I know that's an old post but i would like to share this [1] video I've just uploaded about that old Macbook Pro Late 2011 which is suffering screen glitches. While disassembling the screen I noticed touching a sensor on the display electronic board "fixed" the issue.

In the video, what' i'm touching is the cable which connects the screen to the display logic board. So the issue seems to be in the wire or the socket which interconnects the screen to the display logic board located on the bottom of the screen.

Just in case it helps someone to identify the issue.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlmsRSH_Azk

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried messing around with the lvds connector? (i mean simply disconnecting it and reconnecting again) I'd try that. Also, hot boot or cold boot?

As for the lcd I'd just replace it with the one made specifically for your model, connectors might be diff. like the camera connector, wifi antenna etc. - a lot of catches in general. I guess you could try getting a retina display for your model, retina and non-retina come in the same case

Also, try searching for some louis rossman video on youtube about a problem similar to yours, he's a saint.

Comment: How do you know it's the display and not the GPU/logic board?  Replacing good components without proper diagnosis is an expensive proposition.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it all without luck.